# html canvas text overflow ellipsis

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

Is it possible to draw text on a canvas that has an ellipsis at the end of the text if the text won't fit in the available width and needs to be truncated? Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

There is no standard function.

As I needed one, I made this small function that computes the best fitting string :

```js
function fittingString(c, str, maxWidth) {
  var width = c.measureText(str).width;
  var ellipsis = '…';
  var ellipsisWidth = c.measureText(ellipsis).width;
  if (width<=maxWidth || width<=ellipsisWidth) {
    return str;
  } else {
    var len = str.length;
    while (width>=maxWidth-ellipsisWidth && len-->0) {
      str = str.substring(0, len);
      width = c.measureText(str).width;
    }
    return str+ellipsis;
  }
}
```

where `c` is the 2D context.

You can draw the string normally after having set your font and other drawing parameters of your canvas :

```js
c.fillText(fittingString(c, "A big string that will likely be truncated", 100), 50, 50);
```

Answer (score 7):

Top voted answer causes performance issue when working with large number of text.

Here's adapted version using binary search to speed up the search for right length of string.

```
const binarySearch = ({ max, getValue, match }) => {
  let min = 0;

  while (min <= max) {
    let guess = Math.floor((min + max) / 2);
    const compareVal = getValue(guess);

    if (compareVal === match) return guess;
    if (compareVal < match) min = guess + 1;
    else max = guess - 1;
  }

  return max;
};

const fitString = (
  ctx,
  str,
  maxWidth,
) => {
  let width = ctx.measureText(str).width;
  const ellipsis = '…';
  const ellipsisWidth = ctx.measureText(ellipsis).width;
  if (width <= maxWidth || width <= ellipsisWidth) {
    return str;
  }

  const index = binarySearch({
    max: str.length,
    getValue: guess => ctx.measureText(str.substring(0, guess)).width,
    match: maxWidth - ellipsisWidth,
  });

  return str.substring(0, index) + ellipsis;
};
```

Comment: Nice work, I actually came back to this to post my own binary search solution only to find out there already is one! Went from `~5ms` computation time to `~0.2ms` on average for the `~200` character strings I tested with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did in one of my Vue.js project. Adding bit more code than it's actually needed just because to give you guys context.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <canvas ref='elCanvas'></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

  const elCanvas = ref(null);

  const drawCanvas = async (ctx, canvas) => {
    ctx.font = '400 60px Gilroy';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';

    const truncateText = (text, maxWidth) => {
      const width = ctx.measureText(text).width;
      const ellipsis = width > maxWidth ? '...' : '';
      const len = text.length;
      for (let i = len; i > 0; i--) {
        const str = text.substr(0, i) + ellipsis;
        if (ctx.measureText(str).width <= maxWidth) {
          return str;
        }
      }
      return '';
    };

    ctx.fillText(`From ${truncateText('John Doe The Legend', 500)}`, canvas.width / 2, 512);
  };

  const createImage = () => {
    const canvas = elCanvas.value;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.width = 900;
    canvas.height = 1400;

    drawCanvas(ctx, canvas);
  };

  onMounted(() => createImage());
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

There is not such thing for html5 drawText and would be a bit complicated to implement. You would need loop to trim the string until fits in the desired size.
If text is not rotated or has any other special effect, I would suggest to use a normal div with absolute position and the following CSS style:

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
-o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 100%;
```